# When overriding GetHashCode() should you also factor in the base class's HashCode?

Tags: c#, .net-core, gethashcode

```
class A
{
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public override GetHashCode()
    {
        return Age.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public int Name{get;set;}
    public override GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(base.GetHashCode(), Name);
    }
}
```

Is the `GetHashCode` method in type B how to properly override `GetHashCode`, or would you just calculate the hash code of the fields in type B only?

Comment: "*or would you just calculate the hash code of the fields in type B only*" - in the end, what ever properties aren't part of the hashcode aren't part of the hashcode, its as simple as that. That's your choice...

Comment: So there isn't any general practice its just up to the situation/scenario/developer choice?

Comment: [`GetHashCode` notes for inheritors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-5.0#notes-to-inheritors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `GetHashCode()` is to enable different algorithms to quickly determine if two objects of your class are definitely not equal, before they have to consult a maybe inefficient `Equals` method, and to allow data structures like HashSet or Dictionary to sort objects into buckets.

The only **requirement** for `GetHashCode` is that two objects that compare equal (by the `Equals` method) must produce the same hash code (on the other hand, it is OK if two objects producing the same hash code are not equal).

It is best to construct the hash code so that

- collsions are rare
- but still the implementation is performant.

What is the best way to do this, depends on the nature and usage of your class and only you can decide.

**BTW: It is (in general) a bad idea to include mutable properties in the hash, as this makes it impossible to use your class e.g. as key in a dictionary.**

Comment: oh ya that makes sense now, what would I do though in the case that I have no immutable properties that are unique(readonly)? Not Override GetHashCode()?

Comment: It depends. If you override `Equals`, you *must* override `GetHashCode` - even if you just return 0.